# How can I create sub totals for multiple levels of groups in List & Label

Tags: grouping, multi-level, listlabel

Using List and Label, is it possible to create multiple levels of groups with subtotals?
For example, if my table has the following columns:
Currency
Transaction Date
Transaction Type
Transaction Identifier
Amount

Can I create a report with multiple levels of grouping (e.g. Currency, Transaction Date & Transaction Type)?

I.e. a report which shows:

```
Currency 1  Transaction Date 1  Transaction Type 1  Transaction Identifier 1        250 
Currency 1  Transaction Date 1  Transaction Type 1  Transaction Identifier 2       (300)
    Total for Currency 1, Transaction Date 1, Transaction Type 1                    (50)

Currency 1  Transaction Date 1  Transaction Type 2  Transaction Identifier 3        100 
     Total for Currency 1, Transaction Date 1, Transaction Type 2                   100 

Currency 1  Transaction Date 1  Transaction Type 4  Transaction Identifier 4        125 
Currency 1  Transaction Date 1  Transaction Type 4  Transaction Identifier 5       (500)
    Total for Currency 1, Transaction Date 1, Transaction Type 4                   (375)
                        Total for Currency 1, Transaction Date 1                   (325)

Currency 1  Transaction Date 2  Transaction Type 1  Transaction Identifier 6        (75)
Currency 1  Transaction Date 2  Transaction Type 1  Transaction Identifier 7        600 
Currency 1  Transaction Date 2  Transaction Type 1  Transaction Identifier 8        400 
    Total for Currency 1, Transaction Date 2, Transaction Type 1                    925 

Currency 1  Transaction Date 2  Transaction Type 2  Transaction Identifier 9        100 
Currency 1  Transaction Date 2  Transaction Type 2  Transaction Identifier 10        25 
Currency 1  Transaction Date 2  Transaction Type 2  Transaction Identifier 11       (50)
Currency 1  Transaction Date 2  Transaction Type 2  Transaction Identifier 12      (100)
Currency 1  Transaction Date 2  Transaction Type 2  Transaction Identifier 13       100 
     Total for Currency 1, Transaction Date 2, Transaction Type 2                    75 

Currency 1  Transaction Date 2  Transaction Type 3  Transaction Identifier 14       200 
Currency 1  Transaction Date 2  Transaction Type 3  Transaction Identifier 15       800 
Currency 1  Transaction Date 2  Transaction Type 3  Transaction Identifier 16       100 
  Total for Currency 1, Transaction Date 2, Transaction Type 3                    1,100 
                      Total for Currency 1, Transaction Date 2                    2,100 

Currency 1  Transaction Date 3  Transaction Type 1  Transaction Identifier 17       (50)
Currency 1  Transaction Date 3  Transaction Type 1  Transaction Identifier 18     1,000 
Currency 1  Transaction Date 3  Transaction Type 1  Transaction Identifier 19       350 
   Total for Currency 1, Transaction Date 3, Transaction Type 1                   1,300 

Currency 1  Transaction Date 3  Transaction Type 5  Transaction Identifier 20        75 
    Total for Currency 1, Transaction Date 3, Transaction Type 5                     75 
                      Total for Currency 1, Transaction Date 3                    1,375 
                                          Total for Currency 1                    3,150 

Currency 2  Transaction Date 1  Transaction Type 1  Transaction Identifier 21       (75)
Currency 2  Transaction Date 1  Transaction Type 1  Transaction Identifier 22       600 
Currency 2  Transaction Date 1  Transaction Type 1  Transaction Identifier 23       800 
Currency 2  Transaction Date 1  Transaction Type 1  Transaction Identifier 24       (50)
Currency 2  Transaction Date 1  Transaction Type 1  Transaction Identifier 25       250 
Currency 2  Transaction Date 1  Transaction Type 1  Transaction Identifier 26       350 
Currency 2  Transaction Date 1  Transaction Type 1  Transaction Identifier 27      (300)
  Total for Currency 2, Transaction Date 1, Transaction Type 1                    1,575 

Currency 2  Transaction Date 1  Transaction Type 2  Transaction Identifier 28       100 
Currency 2  Transaction Date 1  Transaction Type 2  Transaction Identifier 29       125 
    Total for Currency 2, Transaction Date 1, Transaction Type 2                    225 

Currency 2  Transaction Date 1  Transaction Type 3  Transaction Identifier 30       400 
    Total for Currency 2, Transaction Date 1, Transaction Type 3                    400 

Currency 2  Transaction Date 1  Transaction Type 4  Transaction Identifier 31     1,000 
  Total for Currency 2, Transaction Date 1, Transaction Type 4                    1,000 
                      Total for Currency 2, Transaction Date 1                    3,200 

Currency 2  Transaction Date 2  Transaction Type 2  Transaction Identifier 32       (50)
Currency 2  Transaction Date 2  Transaction Type 2  Transaction Identifier 33      (100)
   Total for Currency 2, Transaction Date 2, Transaction Type 2                    (150)

Currency 2  Transaction Date 2  Transaction Type 3  Transaction Identifier 34       100 
    Total for Currency 2, Transaction Date 2, Transaction Type 3                    100 

Currency 2  Transaction Date 2  Transaction Type 4  Transaction Identifier 35        25 
    Total for Currency 2, Transaction Date 2, Transaction Type 4                     25 
    Total for Currency 2, Transaction Date 2                                        (25)

Currency 2  Transaction Date 3  Transaction Type 1  Transaction Identifier 36       100 
Currency 2  Transaction Date 3  Transaction Type 1  Transaction Identifier 37      (500)
   Total for Currency 2, Transaction Date 3, Transaction Type 1                    (400)

Currency 2  Transaction Date 3  Transaction Type 2  Transaction Identifier 38       100 
Currency 2  Transaction Date 3  Transaction Type 2  Transaction Identifier 39        75 
    Total for Currency 2, Transaction Date 3, Transaction Type 2                    175 

Currency 2  Transaction Date 3  Transaction Type 5  Transaction Identifier 40       200 
    Total for Currency 2, Transaction Date 3, Transaction Type 5                    200 
                        Total for Currency 2, Transaction Date 3                    (25)
                                          Total for Currency 2                    3,150 

Currency 3  Transaction Date 1  Transaction Type 1  Transaction Identifier 41       200 
Currency 3  Transaction Date 1  Transaction Type 1  Transaction Identifier 42       (50)
Currency 3  Transaction Date 1  Transaction Type 1  Transaction Identifier 43       100 
Currency 3  Transaction Date 1  Transaction Type 1  Transaction Identifier 44       (75)
Currency 3  Transaction Date 1  Transaction Type 1  Transaction Identifier 45       800 
Currency 3  Transaction Date 1  Transaction Type 1  Transaction Identifier 46      (100)
Currency 3  Transaction Date 1  Transaction Type 1  Transaction Identifier 47       250 
Currency 3  Transaction Date 1  Transaction Type 1  Transaction Identifier 48       400 
  Total for Currency 3, Transaction Date 1, Transaction Type 1                    1,525 

Currency 3  Transaction Date 1  Transaction Type 2  Transaction Identifier 49     1,000 
Currency 3  Transaction Date 1  Transaction Type 2  Transaction Identifier 50      (300)
     Total for Currency 3, Transaction Date 1, Transaction Type 2                   700 

Currency 3  Transaction Date 1  Transaction Type 3  Transaction Identifier 51       100 
    Total for Currency 3, Transaction Date 1, Transaction Type 3                    100 

Currency 3  Transaction Date 1  Transaction Type 5  Transaction Identifier 52       600 
    Total for Currency 3, Transaction Date 1, Transaction Type 5                    600 
                      Total for Currency 3, Transaction Date 1                    2,925 

Currency 3  Transaction Date 2  Transaction Type 1  Transaction Identifier 53       100 
Currency 3  Transaction Date 2  Transaction Type 1  Transaction Identifier 54        25 
Currency 3  Transaction Date 2  Transaction Type 1  Transaction Identifier 55       125 
Currency 3  Transaction Date 2  Transaction Type 1  Transaction Identifier 56       350 
    Total for Currency 3, Transaction Date 2, Transaction Type 1                    600 

Currency 3  Transaction Date 2  Transaction Type 2  Transaction Identifier 57       (50)
Currency 3  Transaction Date 2  Transaction Type 2  Transaction Identifier 58        75 
    Total for Currency 3, Transaction Date 2, Transaction Type 2                     25 
                        Total for Currency 3, Transaction Date 2                    625 

Currency 3  Transaction Date 3  Transaction Type 1  Transaction Identifier 59      (500)
   Total for Currency 3, Transaction Date 3, Transaction Type 1                    (500)

Currency 3  Transaction Date 3  Transaction Type 2  Transaction Identifier 60       100 
    Total for Currency 3, Transaction Date 3, Transaction Type 2                    100 
                       Total for Currency 3, Transaction Date 3                    (400)
                                          Total for Currency 3                    3,150
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can have an arbitrary number of group levels. Simply make sure your "Group By" string is taking the hierarchy into account. You'll have three group footers, the first has a "Group By" of `ToString$(Currency)`, the second of `ToString$(Currency)+ToString$(TransactionDate)` and the third of `ToString$(Currency)+ToString$(TransactionDate)+ToString$(TransactionType)`. Note that your data source needs to be sorted accordingly - your excerpt above looks fine in this respect.

For the subtotals, simply add three sum variables for the three levels and choose which one to reset here (it's the same on the group footer tab):

[image: Group Sum in List & Label]

You'll also find a sample for hierarchical groupings in the sample application (Simple Lists > Item Report with Grouping)